# Getting values with angular for dropdown

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I´m working in WebApi Asp.Net with Angular, I want to know how to fill a simple dropdown using select

**View:**

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" name="Catalogo" id="Catalogo" ng-change="filtro('Cat')" ng-model="f.Cat">
  <option value="" selected>TODOS</option>
  <option ng-repeat="item in Catalogos" value="{{item.Nombre}}" label="{{item.Nombre}}"></option>
</select>
<br />
```

**Angular Controller:**

```
(function (app) {
    'use strict';

    app.controller('catalogosGenericosCtrl', catalogosGenericosCtrl);

    catalogosGenericosCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'apiService', 'notificationService', '$rootScope', '$location', '$http', '$state'];

    function catalogosGenericosCtrl($scope, apiService, notificationService, $rootScope, $location, $http, $state) {
        if ($rootScope.Usuario.TipoPerfil != 'Administrador')
            $state.go("root.dashboard");
        $scope.loadingConductores = true;
        $scope.usuario = {};
        $scope.usuario.Origen = 'Web'
        $scope.usuario.Version = $rootScope.VersionWeb;
        $scope.page = 0;
        $scope.pagesCount = 0;
        $scope.Catalogos = [];
        cargarCatalogo();



        function cargarCatalogo() {
            apiService.get("../../api/Catalogos/", null,
                function (res) {
                    $scope.Catalogos = res.data.Nombre; 
                },
                errorCatalogo);
        }

        function errorCatalogo(res) {
            bootbox.alert("Error al cargar el catalogo" + res.data);
        }
    }

})(angular.module('myPortal'));
```

`console.log(res.data)` get 10 different values like:

```
CatalogoPadreId:0
ID:"BAN"
Nombre:"BANKS"
```

From there I only want "Nombre" value into `res.data;, chrome console don´t show any error, and  I didn´t get any value on my dropdown, how can I get Nombre value into my dropdown? what is wong with my code there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ng-options instead of ng-repeat,

```
 <select ng-change="filtro(selected)" ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.Nombre for item in Catalogos">
 </select>
```

Comment: same resut, I don´t get any on my dselect list, I discover that `res.data.Nombre`, when I debugging it `"Nombre"` come undefinied

Comment: I change it for `res.data` and it load now, but how can I select my first value to default?

Comment: just simple you should set like this     $scope.selected = $scope.Catalogos[0];